# invalid ‘static_cast’ from type ‘llvm::MCSection’ to type ‘llvm::MCSectionELF&’

Tags: c++, c++11, static, clang, llvm

While building LLVM 15.0.4 I'm facing the following error:

```
/home/pegasus/Documents/LLVM_Rust/CCR-master/llvm/lib/MC/MCAssembler.cpp: In member function ‘void llvm::MCAssembler::layout(llvm::MCAsmLayout&)’:
/home/pegasus/Documents/LLVM_Rust/CCR-master/llvm/lib/MC/MCAssembler.cpp:1221:28: error: invalid ‘static_cast’ from type ‘llvm::MCSection’ to type ‘llvm::MCSectionELF&’
 1221 |     MCSectionELF &ELFSec = static_cast<MCSectionELF &>(Sec);
```

Here's the code I'm trying to compile. Here it gives invalid static_cast

```
    for (MCFragment &Frag : Sec) {
            
      // Koo - Attach the size of the alignment to the previous fragment.
      //       Here assumes a) no two alignments are consecutive.
      //                    b) data fragment (DF or RF) exists prior to AF. (may be broken in assembly)
      uint64_t fragOffset = Frag.getOffset();
      MCFragment *prevFrag;
      
      if (isa<MCDataFragment>(&Frag) && Frag.hasInstructions())
        prevFrag = static_cast<MCDataFragment*>(&Frag);
    
      if (isa<MCRelaxableFragment>(&Frag) && Frag.hasInstructions())
        prevFrag = static_cast<MCRelaxableFragment*>(&Frag);
    
      // Update alignment size to reflect to the size of MF and MBB
      if (MOFI->getObjectFileType() == llvm::MCObjectFileInfo::IsELF && \
         secName.find(".text") == 0 && (isa<MCAlignFragment>(&Frag)) && fragOffset > 0) {
         // Push this alignment to the previous MBB and the MF that the MBB belongs to
         unsigned alignSize;
         std::string ID;
         if (isa<MCDataFragment>(*prevFrag))
           ID = static_cast<MCDataFragment*>(prevFrag)->getLastParentTag();
         if (isa<MCRelaxableFragment>(*prevFrag))
           ID = static_cast<MCRelaxableFragment*>(prevFrag)->getInst().getParent();
         
         alignSize = computeFragmentSize(Layout, Frag);
         MAI->updateByteCounter(ID, alignSize, 0, /*isAlign=*/ true, /*isInline=*/ false);
      }
```

Rest of the code is shortened.

Comment: You have edited the code, but have not edited the error text and the title. You seem to have another question. Don't edit the question, ask a new one, otherwise the answer becomes unrelated to the edited question.

Comment: The question is rollbacked to the answered state.

Comment: What doess this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your codes does not show  `MCSectionELF &ELFSec = static_cast<MCSectionELF &>(Sec);` and where `Sec` comes from.

`llvm::MCSection Sec` is an object of the exact/concrete type, it can't be casted to a reference of the derived type `llvm::MCSectionELF&` because of strict aliasing rule violation. For making the cast possible, the origin must be a reference `llvm::MCSection &Sec`.

Comment: I've edited the code can you tell me now how to remove the given error?